# WCF local machine ServiceHost and Administrator Privileges

Tags: wcf, privileges, servicehost, netnamedpipebinding

Is there way to run self host a WCF service with ServiceHost on local user (no administrator privileges)? It needs only to be on the local computer.

I'm working on aplication which in future will be installed on multiple desktops, but currently it only needs to work on 1 desktop - both server and client. I would like to use whole wcf stack also in 1 destop app to eliminate future problems. Basically - I need to launch WCF server and client on one system with no administrator privileges. Maybe it can be done with netnamedpipebinding?

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/wcf/thread/b9cdcef2-b39c-498f-b7a9-dbedf3f84163). You can also look into [Juval Lowy's InProc Factory](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=-1&tabid=19&download=232) (you'll have to register to download). This allows to you to automate hosting services in the same process as the client.